# How to disable built-in driver "AHCI" when installing 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, ahci

I need to change AHCI module in Ubuntu, and I've always uses `ahci.blacklist=yes`.

But now it doesn't work bcause AHCI is built-in the kernel, and `CONFIG_SATA_AHCI=y` not `CONFIG_SATA_AHCI=m`.

What can I do now? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `modprobe.blacklist=module_name` to the kernel parameters to blacklist the loading of the module at boot time. You can still insert it later if you need.

So, in the case of the AHCI driver, pass `modprobe.blacklist=ahci` to the kernel.

Comment: Does this *actually* work in this case? The point of the question seems to be that `modprobe.blacklist=ahci` *only* works if the ahci driver is compiled as a module, and the question is how to blacklist the driver when it is built into the kernel.

Comment: @njsg, you are correct, I tested it again to be sure. I also verified that the new 4.8 kernel parameter `module_blacklist=module_name` does not work with built-ins either. The only option is the rebuild the kernel with `CONFIG_SATA_AHCI=m`and use the `modprobe.blacklist` or `module_blacklist` with 4.8+ kernels.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Fedora Common Kernel Problems wiki page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_kernel_problems), to disable AHCI you can add `rdblacklist=ahci` to the boot parameters and disable the functionality. It warns that this should make the system slower.

To add a kernel option, edit the grub configuration file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add in the option you need to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=bios rdblacklist=ahci"
```

Save the file and now regenerate the grub menu using:

```
gksu update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still not work on ubuntu 12.04, AHCI still loaded when boot
ahci 0000:00:11.0: version 3.0
ahci 0000:00:11.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
ahci 0000:00:11.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
ahci 0000:00:11.0: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 6 ports 3 Gpbs 0x3f impl RAID mode
ahci 0000:00:11.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo pmp pio slum part ccc
scsi0 : ahci
scsi1 : ahci
scsi2 : ahci
scsi3 : ahci
scsi4 : ahci
scsi5 : ahci